# Log4j2 Gmail SMTP Appender

Tags: java, xml, smtp, gmail, log4j2

I have a problem, i can't find parameters of SMTP Appender in xml format.

```
<SMTP name="MailAppender"
          subject="Great Notes [PROD]"
          to="example@example.com"
          from="example@example.com"
          smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com"
          smtpPort="587"
          bufferSize="50"
          smtpUsername="example@example.com"
          smtpPassword="*********"
          smtpProtocol="smtps"
          mail.smtp.ssl.enable="true"
          mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
    >

        <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </SMTP>
```

So i can't find parameters for: mail.smtp.ssl.enable & mail.smtp.starttls.enable.

I get this error:

```
ERROR SMTP contains invalid attributes "mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "mail.smtp.ssl.enable"
ERROR SMTP contains invalid attributes "mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "mail.smtp.ssl.enable"



Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;


ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender MailAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: Error occurred while sending email
```

Comment: Those two options are not available on the `SMTPAppender`:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/SmtpAppender.html

Comment: @Dovmo , i found how to override SMTPAppender for log4j https://horrikhalid.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/how-to-use-log4j-with-gmail/. It's possible to override it for log4j2? Could you help me?

Comment: Looks like there are some nice instructions here:
http://www.tgerm.com/2010/05/log4j-smtpappender-gmail-custom.html
Let me know if you have any issues with doing that

Comment: @Dovmo , so did you find anything?

Comment: did you see the link and give it a try?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, because there is no **protected Session createSession()**  in **SmtpAppender.class** ...

Comment: Right, those instructions are for Log4J 1 I just noticed, you need for v2

Comment: Please, can you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, I'll look into it some more and get back to you about it

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following appender configuration and sending some ERROR level messages in a test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

<SMTP name="SmtpAppender" 
        to="myemail@gmail.com" 
        from="myemail@gmail.com"
        smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com" 
        smtpPort="465"
        bufferSize="4"
        smtpUsername="myemail@gmail.com"
        smtpPassword="myPassword"
        smtpProtocol="smtps"
        smtpDebug="true"
        ignoreExceptions="false" 
        subject="Test">

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="SmtpAppender"/>
    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, you'll have to turn off the simple auth setting on the Gmail account doing the sending. Otherwise, it will block the login/send.

Comment: I am still getting 'Username and password not accepted' error. How to turn off Simple auth ?